# Widget promoted to a custom widget in QtDesigner shows up blank

Tags: qt, qt4

When I promote a QWidget to a custom widget in QtDesigner, everything compiles fine, but when I run the program the widget seems to be blank. I have made a very simple demo of this:

Form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

#include "ui_form.h"

class Form : public QWidget, private Ui::Form
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif
```

Form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
}
```

TestWidget.h

```
#ifndef TestWidget_H
#define TestWidget_H

#include "ui_TestWidget.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

class TestWidget : public QWidget, private Ui::TestWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  TestWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

};

#endif
```

TestWidget.cpp

```
#include "TestWidget.h"

TestWidget::TestWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "form.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Form form;

  form.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Form.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>532</width>
    <height>341</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="TestWidget" name="widget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>121</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>TestWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>TestWidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

TestWidget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>TestWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="TestWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>306</width>
    <height>60</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Current path:</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

When I run this, I just see a blank widget, when I would expect to see the label with "Current path:" displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to add

setupUi(this);

to the TestWidget constructor.

Comment: Since you've found the answer you can kind of "close" the question by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I were able to comment I would put this there... need more rep still though before that is an option.

Looking at the geometry of the TestWidget I see that it is 306 pixels wide:

```
<property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    **<width>306</width>**
    <height>60</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
```

In Form.ui, you're giving it only 161 pixels:

```
<widget class="TestWidget" name="widget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>90</y>
     **<width>161</width>**
     <height>121</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
```

Might that be part of the problem - the label is there, it is just outside of the painted area for the widget?